# Magento 2 Installation Issue with file permission and missing resources

Tags: magento2

So far my experience with magento 2 hasn't been great. I've been trying to configure magento on a hosting for 3 long days. Previously after installation, it only loads one time and then keep giving me a broken screen with missing resources. I've tried every solution god google blessed me with, but no success. I've tried removing content from pub/static/. I've tried changing app/etc/di.xml as many have suggested, still the problem persist. I've even changed permissions to directories, nothing helped. After all the hard work i've changed permissions of var/ and pub/static to 777 and it FINALLY worked.

Now, even i can load my site properly, there still are some missing resources on front end and backend as well.
See, frontend:
http://screencast.com/t/hhqu1SEyu

On backend, problem is even worse:
http://screencast.com/t/DqVzxnMhqOw

I can't even change store configuration, it just keeps loading.

Can someone possibly help me out with what could be the possible issue causing this?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you create a magento user as recommended? Then you shouldn't have to assign 777 permissions.  See issue with similar problems http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36301066/css-not-working-after-installation-in-magento-2/36405944

Comment: that is not my primary concern now, since it is working for now. The main issue is i can't change configuration of store. Let's say i want to change my theme, it just keeps loading without success.

Comment: So now, this is a different issue, can you please update with steps you followed to change theme?

Comment: Well, what i think is, this is the part of the problem you initially pointed out, because after repeatedly assigning permission to pub/static and refreshing the issue is gone. I understand what you are suggesting here but as a windows user i'm not familiar with this process. Also, i'm not sure if my hosting will allow that.